# Firefox HTML input type time

Tags: html, forms, firefox

I am using Firefox 72.0.1, I have a form element like this

```
<input type="time" step="60" name="stime" id="stime" value="">
```

If a user in Slovakia with either Slovak or Hungarian Windows locale enters data instead of a box containing --:-- they see one like --:  -- ,two extra spaces after the colon, the numbers they enter appear here, so if I enter half past twelve I see 12:30, they see 12:30--, and the data entered does not appear in the POST array from their PC

EDIT - it seems this is a keyboard language issue, if my Slovak users change keybaord language to EN-US or EN-GB the form works as it should (apart from the display weirdness)

Any workarounds, or should I just dump it and use some Javascript to capture this data?

Comment: According to the [MDN article on time input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time), the two dashes at the end are for AM/PM and will be displayed based on the OS's locale.

Comment: But Slovakia doesn't use AM/PM, their clock is naturally 24 hour and always has been, Hungary same, so they can't add any characters in place of those two dashes. 

Locale may be part of the problem, but it seems keyboard language is in combination with it.

With Slovakia locale, SK keyboard language, user sees --:  --, enters 19:15--, can not any more characters, POST is empty. Same user changes language to EN-GB, sees same, enters same, data is in POST.

Input type date works fine, consistently changes through British, Slovak and Korean locales and POSTs the data as ISO